# Use a class library DLL hosted on an ASPX webpage

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll

I'm developing a webpage using the ASP.net Framework 4.0, C# and I got a DLL from a class Library. The function of this DLL is to activate and read information from a hardware CARD-READER (Client side) then I want to send the information to the server.

How can I use this DLL from a ASPX webpage?

Comment: Right click on the website or web project from Solution explorer, click Add Reference and select the dll file.

Comment: You would use this dll like you do it on a windows application, add the reference and start calling it's methods from your webpage, i.e from a click event of a button

Comment: Take in consideration if the app is web and you need hardware access this can be a challenge, not impossible

Comment: Thanks for the answer......Actually this this is the problem i need to activate the hardware reading a COM port(Client Side) i have read about hosting dll in webpage ActiveX Controls and Click-once application but i doesn't work for me yet.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the downloaded DLL file in a custom folder on your drive, hopefully at the root of your solution maybe in a libs folder, then add the reference to your project using the Browse button in the Add Reference dialog. Make sure that the new reference has Copy Local = True set within its properties once added to the solution, which is found when un-collapsing and right-clicking on the References item in your project within Solution Explorer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer......Actually this this is the problem i need to activate the hardware reading a COM port(Client Side) i have the logic of this in a class library dll but when i add reference etc...and i use the page as a client(Browsing in IE) it doesn't work cause this is server side i need to host the dell the asp.net webpage, i have read about hosting dll in webpage ActiveX Controls like applets java and Click-once application but i doesn't work for me yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can host it creating a XBAP, silverlight or clickonce application. The created application will run clientside.

Hope this helps.

Regards.